# pure css iframe responsive with given proportion

Tags: html, css, iframe

```css
div.scroll {
    position:absolute;
 -moz-transform: rotate(-7deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(-7deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-7deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-7deg);
 background-color: #00FFFF;
    width: 190px;
    height: 250px;
 overflow: scroll;
 z-index:1;
 margin:0 auto;
 left:220px;
 top:68px;
 
}
size {
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height:100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="size"><div class="scroll"><iframe src="http://www.kopfkino-kollektiv.de"></iframe></div></div>
```

Im coding a portfolio site and i have a problem with iframe.
wether it has my given ratio OR it is responsive! i need both! as you can see in the screenshot i need to hover the iframe exaxtly over the ipads screen at all time ! can you guys help me?

HTML

```
     <div class="size"><div class="scroll"><iframe src="http://www.kopfkino-kollektiv.de"></iframe></div></div>
```

CSS

```
        div.scroll {
position:absolute;
-moz-transform: rotate(-7deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-7deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-7deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-7deg);
background-color: #00FFFF;
width: 190px;
height: 250px;
overflow: scroll;
z-index:1;
margin:0 auto;
left:220px;
top:68px;
}


  size {
max-width: 100%;
max-height:100%;
}
```

SCREENSHOT

[now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbSHT.png)

[should](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67pA5.png)

Comment: Your screenshots don't appear!

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle or jsbin to recreate the problem?

Comment: the screenshots do now work ! i create a jsfiddler just now !

Comment: wat R the desired sizes?

Comment: that it fits the ipads screen img

Answer (score 0):

1. Style the `iframe` to take up 100% `width` and `height` of parent container, and
2. Fix parent `.scroll` container to remove forced scrollbars via `scroll:auto` and either remove the whitespace or use `font-size:0` to prevent issues caused by the whitespace in your markup (otherwise two sets of scrollbars may appear).
3. Adjust the `iframe` `margin` or position as needed to get the correct overlay. But you didn't include link to background image, so I can't show you this until you do that.

```css
div.scroll {
  position: absolute;
  -moz-transform: rotate(-7deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-7deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-7deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-7deg);
  background-color: #00FFFF;
  width: 190px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 220px;
  top: 68px;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
size {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="size">
  <div class="scroll">
    <iframe src="http://www.kopfkino-kollektiv.de"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```